# Is the free product $\mathbb{Z}*\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ a linear group?

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory

Let $H:=\mathbb{Z}*\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}=\langle p,q| q^n=1\rangle.$ I want to know if $H$ is a ($\mathbb{Z}$)linear group that is to say is there an injective homomorphism $f: H\to GL_m(\mathbb{Z})$ for $m\geq n.$ I suggested a homomorphism in a previous question but I didn't manage to prove its injectivity. By advance thank you.

Comment: What homomorphism did you suggest?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1413634/kernel-of-homomorphism

Comment: have you tried some ping pong argument?

Comment: However, it's a fact that you have H a subgroup of $GL_N( \mathbb{Q}(t))$ (for some N depending on 2 I guess), but I don't know if this helps, since I don't know your motivation for your question.

Comment: You could try asking this on mathoverflow (but include a link to the question here).

Comment: I answered this on mathoverflow http://mathoverflow.net/questions/218120/is-the-free-product-mathbbz-mathbbz-n-mathbbz-linear-over-mathbbz/218129#218129